# JS: Sum of span values in For loop

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, sum, type-conversion

I have the following values within span tags:

```
<div id="aantallen">
 <span>3</span>
 <span>2</span>
</div>
```

In JS I want to get the sum of these values. So I made the following For Loop:

```
var div = document.getElementById("aantallen");
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");
for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++)
{
    var totaalPersonen = totaalPersonen + i;
    alert(totaalPersonen);
}
```

However, the 3 and 2 are text, so I get Nan in the alerts. My question: how can in convert the 3 and 2 into strings so that I can make a sum of these values?

I tried with `String(i)` but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the content of the `DOM` element to a `Number`.
Then, you can use `reduce` in order to calculate the sum.

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('#aantallen span');

const result = Array.from(spans).reduce((sum, spanElm) => sum + Number(spanElm.textContent), 0)

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="aantallen">
  <span>3</span>
  <span>2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the input!

Comment: You might want to specifically target the id: `querySelectorAll('#aantallen span')`.

Comment: Updated, thanx.

Answer (score 0):

To convert string to Int in Javascript, Use:

parseInt(totaalPersonen);

Answer (score 0):

You are reintializing `var totaalPersonen = totaalPersonen + i;` in every loop.
So you need to initialize `totaalPersonen` outside the loop like this `var totaalPersonen = 0;` and inside the loop just count it up like `totaalPersonen = totaalPersonen + 1;` or just `totaalPerseonen++;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Assuming you are wanting to add the text inside the spans I have used `innerHTML`, and not `i`.
Also, the `totaalPersonen` variable should be declared outside the for loop otherwise it will be reinitialized each time.

```
var div = document.getElementById("aantallen");
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");
console.log(spans);
var totaalPersonen = 0;
for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++)
{
    alert(parseInt(spans[i].innerHTML));
    totaalPersonen = parseInt(totaalPersonen) + parseInt(spans[i].innerHTML);
    //alert(totaalPersonen);
}
alert(totaalPersonen);
```